# “R CMD build” fails with “Error in texi2dvi”

Tags: r, vignette

I'm having new problems with the “sos” package that has been on CRAN since 2009.  One problem is that “R CMD build sos” fails as follows:

```
>* creating vignettes ... ERROR
><snip>
>Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, 
>        clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
>  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'sos.tex' failed.
>LaTeX errors:
>! Undefined control sequence.
>l.1 \Sconcordance
>                 {concordance:sos.tex:sos.Rnw:%
>The control sequence at the end of the top line
>of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
>Calls: <Anonymous> -> texi2pdf -> texi2dvi
>Execution halted
```

[The package is available on R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=235).  The log file [(build_src) is also available there](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=235&log=build_src&pkg=sos&flavor=patched)  This is the message from R 3.3.1 on R-Forge.  I get a similar but slightly different message form R 3.3.0 on my Mac OS X running 10.11.5.

This build log suggests that the problem is with the “sos” vignette.  However, if it were a problem with the vignette, I would expect to see it when I click “Compile PDF” in RStudio 0.99.902.  Instead, that claims to run to completion, producing “sos.pdf”.  (That output has other problems, but that's a subject for another post.)

Thanks,

Comment: I would suggest the following: create a *minimal* dummy package from scratch, for debugging purposes. Then place in it a bare-bones version of this problematic vignette, adding more content until it breaks. Don't use Rstudio's buttons to compile, but plain command line. It may seem too much work, but looking at your stream of questions, I feel it's the fastest route.

Comment: Someone privately suggested removing the following line in the vignette:

    \SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

The package builds just fine after doing that.

Comment: NOTE:  After I removed that line, I clicked, "Compile PDF" in RStudio, and the line reappeared.  RStudio is a really great product, but this feature introduces a latent bug that, in my case, was introduced clandestinely a month before I was aware of it.  And then it took me several days and several requests for help on different fora before someone identified the problem for me.

Comment: removing `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` works for me as well